# recursion function with awk

Tags: awk

Given a csv describing firstname and lastname of parent-child relationship

```
$ cat /var/tmp/hier
F2 L2,F1 L1
F3 L3,F1 L1
F4 L4,F2 L2
F5 L5,F2 L2
F6 L6,F3 L3
```

I want to print:

```
F1 L1
    F2 L2
        F4 L4
        F5 L5
    F3 L3
        F6 L6
```

I wrote a script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
print_node() {
        echo "awk -F, '\$2=="\"$@\"" {print \$1}' /var/tmp/hier"
        for node in `eval "awk -F, '\$2=="\"$@\"" {print \$1}'     /var/tmp/hier"`
        do
                echo -e "\t"$node
                print_node "$node"
        done
}
print_node "$1"
```

run the script:

```
$ ./print_tree.sh "F1 L1"
awk -F, '$2=="F1 L1" {print $1}' /var/tmp/hier
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

It seemed that the awk command was malformed. but if I run the command shown in the debug output, it works:

```
$ awk -F, '$2=="F1 L1" {print $1}' /var/tmp/hier
F2 L2
F3 L3
```

Could anyone point out what is causing this error?

=======================

@moderatoors:
I added perl and python tags because I'd welcome solutions in perl or python code. take no offence, please.

Comment: I'm not seeing the connection to python here to justify the tag, am I missing something?

Comment: Anything containing ```for node in `eval "awk ...` ``` is sufficiently complex that you should be rethinking from the ground up.  I for one simply decline to spend time working out what you're trying to do, and why your code isn't achieving it.  You should be able to run `awk` once, and it should do all the processing.  (Or Perl, or Python, or …)

Comment: Please either explain why [tag:perl] and [tag:python] are relevant tags, or stop adding irrelevant tags.

Comment: Whenever you get that specific error message it means you are trying to use old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or nawk as a second best choice)

Comment: replacing with /usr/xpg4/bin/awk didn't work.

Comment: If by "didn't work" you mean your script still didn't produce the output you wanted, that is no surprise, but using that awk instead of the one you've been trying to use is like the difference between having an engine in your car vs having a banana. Your car still may not run but at least it's no longer guaranteed to not run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally reach for Perl here; you could also do Python (or any other similar-level language that happens to be there, like Ruby or Tcl, but Perl and Python are almost universally preinstalled). I would use one of them since they have built-in nested data structures, which make it easy to cache the tree in navigable form, instead of re-parsing the parent links every time you want to fetch a node's children. (GNU awk has arrays of arrays, but BSD awk doesn't.)

Anyway, here's one perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %parent;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($child, $parent) = split ',';
  $parent{$child} = $parent;
}

my (%children, %roots);

while (my ($child, $parent) = each %parent) {
  push @{$children{$parent} ||= []}, $child;
  $roots{$parent} = 1 unless $parent{$parent};
}

foreach my $root (sort keys %roots) {
  show($root);
}

sub show {
  my ($node, $indent) = (@_,'');
  print "$indent$node\n";
  foreach my $child (sort(@{$children{$node}||[]})) {
    show($child, "    $indent");
  }
}
```

I saved the above as `print_tree.pl` and ran it like this on your data:

```
$ perl print_tree.pl *csv
```

You could also make it executable with `chmod +x print_tree.pl` and run it without explicitly calling `perl`:

```
$ ./print_tree.pl *csv
```

Anyway, on your sample data, it produces this output:

```
F1 L1
    F2 L2
        F4 L4
        F5 L5
    F3 L3
        F6 L6
```

Comment: Great. Thank you Mark.

Answer (score 7):

With GNU awk for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
function descend(node) {
    printf "%*s%s\n", indent, "", node
    if ( isarray(map[node]) ) {
        indent += 3
        for (child in map[node]) {
            descend(child)
        }
        indent -= 3
    }
    return
}
NR==1 { root = $2 }
{ map[$2][$1] }
END { descend(root) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
F1 L1
   F2 L2
      F4 L4
      F5 L5
   F3 L3
      F6 L6
```

Comment: Just brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

alternative solution without multi dimensional awk arrays which works for this hierarchy

```
join -t, -1 1 -2 2 inputfile{,} | awk -F, -f tree.awk
```

and awk script is as follows

```
$ cat tree.awk 
    {
            s=$1;$1=$2;$2=s;
            t=""
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                    if (! ($i in n)) {
                            print t $i
                            n[$i]
                    }
                    t=t "\t"
            }
    }
```

Comment: Correct, you have keep joining to create the full path for each node.