# how to parse a file in bash, awk... for linking program and subprogram in a more efficient way

Tags: bash, loops, awk, tree, ksh

I have the need to generate a tree view for a list of program and subprogram we actually use.

we have a working script right now (in ksh), but it's take a very long time to achieve (between 3 and 4 hours), and i'm pretty sure it can be done more efficiently/quickly

the actual working script is using two files :
1 : the list of program we actually using (2926 lines)
2 : the list of all programs and subprograms associated to this program (23922 lines)

for better comprehension, this is a representation of the file 2 :

```
A|B C D E
B|F G
C|J K L
E|
K|Z
L|M N
Z|Y X
```

the program A call the subprograms B, C, D and E
The program B (called by A) call the subprogram F and G
The program C (called by A) call the subprogram J K and L
etc...

from this two files, we need to write a csv file who represent the tree view of all the programs we use in the first file.

This is the expected output from the previous representation:

```
A
;B
;;F
;;G
;C
;;J
;;K
;;;Z
;;;;Y
;;;;X
;;L
;;;M
;;;N
;E
```

To achieve that, this is what we actually do :

part of the main script who call the csv_tree.sh :

```
#!/bin/ksh
cat program_list | awk -F "|" '{print($2)}' | sort | uniq >program_list.tmp
while read -r line; do
    begin=$(echo "$line" | awk -F "|" '{print $1}')
    sh csv_tree.sh "$begin" 2>/dev/null
done <$HOME/FISCALITE/OSCAR/FICHIER_IMPORT/FIC_PRG_TREE.tmp
#delete temporary file
rm program_list.tmp
```

csv_tree.sh :

```
#!/bin/ksh
#set -x
entry_file="T_SS_PRG_N1"
output_csv_file="${1}_tree.csv"
: >"$output_csv_file"
echo $1 >>"$output_csv_file"
count=0
rank=0
chaine=$(grep -E "^$1" $entry_file | awk '{$1=""}1')
#function loop
loop() {
    rank=$((rank + 1))
    for prg in $2; do
        count=$((count + 1))
        if [[ -n $(echo ${prg} | grep ${chaine}) ]]; then
            rank=1
        fi
        #   calculate the number of ";" to print in the csv file
        separator=$(for ((i = 0; i < rank; ++i)); do echo -n ";"; done)
        echo "${separator}${prg}" >>"$output_csv_file"
        if [ $(echo ${prg} | egrep "^(X|Y|Z)") != "" ] && [ $(grep "^${prg}" ${entry_file} | awk -F\| '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ') != "" ]; then
            echo "${separator};$(grep "^${prg}" ${entry_file} | awk -F\| '{print $2}')" >>"$output_csv_file"
        else
            loop "${prg}_$count" "$(grep -E "^$prg" $entry_file | awk '{$1=""}1')"
            rank=$((rank - 1))
        fi
    done
}

#begin
loop "$1" "$chaine"
```

I'm pretty sure we can achieve this with pure awk, but i'm not really into it :/

If someone have some tips or other way to do it better, i'm wide open ^^

Comment: Can you ever have a cycle in the input, e.g. where E calls A, even if it's a mistake in the input? If so, how should that be displayed? Can A and B both call C? If so how should that be displayed? You say "we need to write a csv file..." but then the expected output you show is not a CSV (not comma-separated and not the same number of fields on each line) so please [edit] your question to resolve that contradiction.

Comment: In general you should use a recursive-descent function in an awk script for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32020697/1745001 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/42736174/1745001 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834902/1745001 for a starting point at least on how to do what you want.

Comment: Please also clarify what "i'm not really into it" means in your statement "I'm pretty sure we can achieve this with pure awk, but i'm not really into it :/" - does it mean you don't know how to use awk but are willing to learn or you do not want a solution that uses awk or something else? If it means you don't want a solution using it then you should remove it's tag from your question and also state what other tools you do not want to use.

Comment: Just being curious: How are recursive programs represented? As `P:P`?

Comment: Since you are concerned about performance, I would not write this in `bash`. The information, which program calls which, is called a _call-graph_, and I would write it in a language, which makes handling directed graphs convenient, for instance Ruby or Java or C++. The main performance penality in your approach comes IMO from the many childprocesses for each single piece of input - this is insane, and you can be happy that it runs only for hours and not days.

Comment: All good comments above. A basic question *"it's take a very long time [hours]*". ... How many files are being processed? You're not running this on a 386 PC are you (-;? Go with links that Ed has listed. Oh, and your headline "* linking program and subprogram in a more efficient way"*, you know about `make` and all of those similar tools, right? Good luck.

Comment: your main script includes - `sort | uniq` - does this imply there are duplicate lines in `file2`?

Comment: you mention `file1` and `file2` but only show the contents of `file2` ... please update the question to show the contents of `file1` (corresponding with the contents of `file2`); in your code I'm assuming `file2 == program_list` ... is this correct? which of the files (in your code) represent `file1` ... `T_SS_PRG_N1` ?

Comment: @markp-fuso,  yes,  there is duplicate entry in the file 1.
this is a part of the file 1 (the second column represent the A B etc in the exemple):
`TNI01A001|TNIC01|SHELL|
TNI02C001|TNID0B|COBOL|
TNI02D001|TNID0D|COBOL|
TNI03C001|TNID0B|COBOL|
TNI03D001|TNID0D|COBOL|
TNI06A001|TNID0H|COBOL|
TNI06B001|TNID0F|COBOL|`

file1 = program_list and file2 = T_SS_PRG_N1

Comment: @EdMorton
I will try your links.
when i say i'm not into it, i don't really know awk outside the basic use, but i'm not closed to use it

Comment: OK, please address [my first comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096985/how-to-parse-a-file-in-bash-awk-for-linking-program-and-subprogram-in-a-more?noredirect=1#comment135913567_77096985) and make sure the sample input/output you provide in your question includes all of the use cases, including duplicates, cycles, multiple parents, recursive calls, etc. as discussed in the comments so we can help you.

Comment: you've gone from `A|B C D E` to `TNI01A001|TNIC01|SHELL|` ... from spaces as delimiters to pipes as delimiters, plus a trailing pipe; while `A|B C D E` is appreciated as a 'minimal' example, the example should (at a minimum) mimic important characteristics of your actual data (eg, delimiters, do names include white space or characters other than alphabetics and numbers, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- we are to generate trees only for root programs (root program == a program that is not called by other programs)
- OP has multiple root programs
- OP mentions two files - `File1` and `File2` - but uses other names in the actual code
- I'm guessing `File2` == `program_list`
- we're not shown the contents of `File1` so I'm proceeding as if `File1` does not exist; OP will likely need to modify the proposed code (below) based on the purpose of `File1`

We'll duplicate OP's sample data to include 2 root programs (`A` and `A1`):

```
$ cat program_list
A|B C D E
B|F G
C|J K L
E|
K|Z
L|M N
Z|Y X
A1|B1 C1 D1 E1
B1|F1 G1
C1|J1 K1 L1
E1|
K1|Z1
L1|M1 N1
Z1|Y1 X1
```

While other languages are going to have better performance, here's one approach using `bash` that should have better performance than OP's current code (if simply because it does not invoke any subshells):

```
$ cat build_tree.bash
#!/bin/bash

unset   pc c p r                                 # just in case script is sourced
declare -A c p r                                 # associative arrays for p(arent), c(hild) and r(oot) nodes

#######
# parse data into p[], c[] and parent_child ( pc_<parent>[] ) arrays

while read -r line
do
    IFS='[ |]' read -ra a <<< "${line}"          # a[0]==parent, a[1-n]==children

    parent="${a[0]}"

    p[$parent]=1
    declare -n pc=pc_"${parent}"                 # nameref to create pc_<parent>=( children ) arrays, eg: pc_A=( B C D E )
    pc=()

    for ((i=1 ; i<${#a[@]} ; i++))               # loop through child nodes
    do
        child="${a[$i]}"
        c[$child]=1                              # add as index in c[] array; c[] used in next loop to determine which nodes are roots
        pc+=( "$child" )                         # add child to pc == pc_<parent>[] array
    done
done < program_list                              # process File2

#######
# determine root nodes

for node in "${!p[@]}"                           # loop through p[] array indices
do
    [[ -z "${c[$node]}" ]] && r[$node]=1         # if not an index in the c[] array then add as index in the r[] array
done

unset child                                      # no longer needed so go ahead and release memory

#######
# recursive function
#
# for a given parent:
# - loop through array of children
# - print a child and if the child has children then make recursive call

recurse() {
    local parent pfx pc child

    parent="$1"                                  # eg: A, B, D1
    pfx="$2"                                     # eg: ';', ';;', ';;;'

    declare -n pc=pc_"${parent}"                 # nameref for pc_<parent>[] array

    for child in "${pc[@]}"                      # loop through child nodes
    do
        echo "${pfx}${child}"                    # print child node

        # if child is also a parent then make recursive call

        [[ -n "${p[$child]}" ]] && recurse "${child}" "${pfx}${sep}"
    done
}

#######
# main step: loop through root nodes and make top-level recurse() calls

sep=';'

for root in "${!r[@]}"
do
    echo "########### new tree:"
    echo "${root}"
    recurse "${root}" "${sep}"
done

#######
# release memory ... just in case script is sourced

for parent in "${!p[@]}"
do
    declare -n pc=pc_"${parent}"                 # nameref for pc_<parent>[] array
    unset pc
done

unset c p r
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `bash 4.2+` for nameref (`declare -n`) support

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./build_tree.bash
########### new tree:
A
;B
;;F
;;G
;C
;;J
;;K
;;;Z
;;;;Y
;;;;X
;;L
;;;M
;;;N
;D
;E
########### new tree:
A1
;B1
;;F1
;;G1
;C1
;;J1
;;K1
;;;Z1
;;;;Y1
;;;;X1
;;L1
;;;M1
;;;N1
;D1
;E1
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your response.
i am really limited about software to use (actually bash 3.2 on the server, no ruby and no java), but c++ is available so i will probably give it a chance :)

Comment: `bash 3.2` is extremely old; you should have your sysadmin seriously consider updating the OS/software on your servers; this would include `bash` (any other shells commonly used in your env), `awk`, `sed`, `grep` and whatever 'common' software is in use (eg, `perl`, `java`, etc)

Comment: Sadly that can't be done, it's an old piece of software with a lots of interconnected programs in the healthcare industry.
they don't want to take the risk of updating a thing and break something else

Answer (score 0):

In [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ cat file1
A
B
C
E
L
$ cat file2
A|B C D E
B|F G
C|J K L
E|
K|Z
L|M N
Z|Y X
$ txr deps.tl file1 file2
A
;B
;;F
;;G
;C
;;J
;;K
;;;Z
;;;;Y
;;;;X
;;L
;;;M
;;;N
;D
;E
B
;F
;G
C
;J
;K
;;Z
;;;Y
;;;X
;L
;;M
;;N
E
L
;M
;N
```

Code looks like:

```
(defstruct mod ()
  name
  children)

(defvarl mh (hash))

(defun resolve-names (m)
  (when (and m.children
             (stringp (first m.children)))
    (set m.children
         (append-each ((c m.children))
           (iflet ((cm [mh c]))
             (list cm))))))

(defun print-tree (m : path (prefix ""))
  (put-line `@prefix@{m.name}`)
  (unless (member m path)
    (let ((nprefix `;@prefix`)
          (npath (cons m path)))
      (each ((c m.children))
        (print-tree c npath nprefix)))))

(tree-bind (file1 file2) *args*
  (let ((used (file-get-lines "file1"))
        (deps (file-get-lines "file2")))
    ;; populate object hash with each definition
    (each ((d deps))
      (match `@left|@right` d
        ;; look up or create new node for left side
        (let ((m (or [mh left]
                     (set [mh left] (new mod name left))))
              (ch (tok #/\S+/ right)))
          ;; ensure node exists for each child
          (each ((c ch))
            (or [mh c] (set [mh c] (new mod name c))))
          ;; append children to left hand node
          (set m.children (append m.children ch)))))
    ;; convert child names to objects
    (dohash (n m mh)
      (resolve-names m))
    ;; print tree view for each used object
    (each ((u used))
      (iflet ((m [mh u]))
        (print-tree m)))))
```

There is a check in `print-tree` against circular references, but not against duplicates (diamond references).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response
sadly i can't install a new piece of software, and no TXR on the server :/

Comment: Why wouldn't you get the data off the server and do the analysis elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
A|B C D E
B|F G
C|J K L
E|
K|Z
L|M N
Z|Y X
```

then

```
awk 'function getpath(name){return (name in arr)?sprintf("%-10s%-10s",getpath(arr[name]),name):sprintf("%-10s",name)}function printasrecord(path){patsplit(path,parts,/.{10}/);depth=length(parts);$0="";$depth=parts[depth];print}BEGIN{FS="[| ]";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";OFS=";"}/[|]./{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){arr[$i]=$1}}END{for(i in arr){paths[getpath(i)]};for(j in paths){printasrecord(j)}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
;B         
;;F         
;;G         
;C         
;;J         
;;K         
;;;Z         
;;;;X         
;;;;Y         
;;L         
;;;M         
;;;N         
;D         
;E
```

Explanation: I process `file.txt` and create array `arr` where key is child and value is its' parent. Then I use recent recursive function `getpath` to get all paths as keys of other array, which are presented in fixed-width format, I selected value of 10, however if you have longer than that adjust it accordingly. This allow to use alphabetical order sorting to get desired output. I inform GNU `AWK` that such ordering is needed by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to `@ind_str_asc` (see [Controlling Scanning for possible values](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)). I traverse paths array in that manner, for each key (path) I parse it using [`patsplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) into parts, then I set current line (`$0`) to empty string and set `depth`th field to value of `depth`th part of path, which is last part. Observe that output is slightly different from desired output presented, as there is not `A` (which has not parent) and order at same depth is dictated by alphabetical sorting, so `X` comes before `Y`.

**Disclaimer:** my solution assumes you are working with directed, acyclic, connected graph, where each element has at most 1 direct ancestor

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: you're missing the root of the tree (ie, `A`)

Comment: Your code would be much easier to understand if you added some white space - blanks between symbols, newlines at the end of statements, indentation following control constructs, etc. If you run your code through `gawk -o-` to pretty-print it you'll see the difference.